# How to add ColSpan for a ImageView in a TableLayout Android dynamically

Tags: android

I am creating  table row dynamically and adding ImageView in it.
but i cant able to add ColSpan for the Imageview. Can you tell me how to add colspan for ImageView dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

try puttin this in your xml

```
android:layout_span="2"
```

or in the code you can use something like this

```
TableRow.LayoutParams params = (TableRow.LayoutParams)yourComponent.getLayoutParams();
params.span = yourSpan;
yourComponent.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: then mark the answer as correct please, then another user can be helped with this thread.